# SQL Server агрегация по группам

Tags: sql-server

Есть таблица:

```
code model  color   type    price
1   1276    n   Laser   400.0000
2   1433    y   Jet     270.0000
3   1434    y   Jet     290.0000
4   1401    n   Matrix  150.0000
5   1408    n   Matrix  270.0000
6   1288    n   Laser   400.0000
```

Необходим разделить таблицу на группы по полю `Color`, каждое значение `Color='n'` создает новую группу, сортировка по полю `Code` и для каждой группы посчитать среднее по полю `Price` и количество уникальных значений `Type`

Т.е, итоговая таблица должна выглядеть так:

```
code model  color   type    price Group Distinct_cnt AVG_price
1   1276    n   Laser   400.0000  1      2           320
2   1433    y   Jet     270.0000  1      2           320
3   1434    y   Jet     290.0000  1      2           320
4   1401    n   Matrix  150.0000  2      1           150
5   1408    n   Matrix  270.0000  3      1           270
6   1288    n   Laser   400.0000  4      1           400
```

Предполагаю, что это можно сделать с помощью оконных функций, но не понимаю, как корректно указать условие для разбивки на группы,чтобы запись с `Code=3` относилась к 1 группе. К тому же, при попытке использовать `Distinct` в оконной функции получаю ошибку `Use of DISTINCT is not allowed with the OVER clause.`

```
select *, 
row_number () over (partition by color order by code) as [group]
--, count (distinct type) over (partition by color order by code) as cnt_distinct
, avg (price) over (partition by color order by code) as avg_price
from printer
order by code
```

SQL Server 2019, фиддл [тут](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2aa09e01fd1b275a2d072eafd08f5016)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select *,
       avg(price) over(partition by grp) avg_price,
       sum(is_new) over(partition by grp) distinct_type_cnt
  from (
    select *,
         case when lag(type,1,'') over(partition by grp order by type) != type then 1 else 0 end is_new
      from (
        select *, sum(case color when 'n' then 1 end) over (order by code) as grp
          from printer
      ) x
  ) y
order by code
```

тестовый [фиддл](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4db17b4bc7fbb44fb0c7a202b2a12ad4)

Внутренний подзапрос (`x`) получает номер группы суммируя 1 для каждого color=n. Подзапрос `y` выставляет в поле is_new 1 если обнаружено новое значение поля type, по сравнению с предыдущей (сортировка по type в группе) строкой. Во внешнем запросе остается получить среднее для группы и сумму "новых" значений type.

Answer (score 3):

или чуток по другому

```
SELECT * ,
   dense_rank() over (partition by  [group] order by  type) + dense_rank() over (partition by  [group] order by type desc) - 1 as distinct_type_cnt,
   avg(price) over(partition by  [group]) avg_price
from (select *, 
             sum(case color when 'n' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by code) as [group]    
      from printer ) AS printer
order by code
```

идея всё та же
тестовый [фиддл](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a05e0ff78297afdde163537d7240fd77)

за разницей реализации [distinct_type_cnt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202878/partition-function-count-over-possible-using-distinct). Получаем - 1 подзапрос.

Comment: отметил вариант @Mike т.к. он предложил его первым. Но ваш так же работает, спасибо)

Comment: Ваше право, ни кто не оспаривает. :))